# не получается считать данные с формы html

Tags: php, html, form

у меня есть форма, после заполнения которой данные отправляются по почте. только вот данные вытащить не получается.

как можно исправить ситуацию?

**index.html**:

```
<form name="form1" action="send.php" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                Email Address</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">
                                Subject</label>
                            <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                                <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                                <option value="service">General Customer Service</option>
                                <option value="suggestions">Suggestions</option>
                                <option value="product">Product Support</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message"         class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                                placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                            Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

**send.php**:

```
<?php
switch ($_POST['form1']) {
  default:
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mes=$_POST['message'];
}
    break;
}
    $to="mymail";
    $from_email="mail";
    $tema="zayavka";
    $pismo="Новый пользователь с именем $name отправил сообщение на тему $subject!\r\n
    Вот его сообщение: $mes.<br>\r\n
    E-mail: $email";
      mail_utf8($to,'novaya zayavka',$from_email, $tema, $pismo);
      function mail_utf8($to, $from_user, $from_email,$tema, $pismo)
         {
            $from_user = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($from_user)."?=";
            $tema = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($tema)."?=";
            $headers = "From: $from_user <$from_email>\r\n".
                     "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n".
                     'Content-type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"'.'\r\n';
           return mail($to, $tema, $pismo, $headers);
         }
         if($realname)
            mail_utf8($to,$from_email, $tema, $pismo);
?>
```

Comment: Нет у вас этого `$_POST['form1']` в пришедших данных ни при каких условиях. Смотрите в `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: @Visman можете поподробней описать? просто только начал со всем этим работать

Comment: А что есть `mail_utf8()`? И какая кодировка на самом сайте?

Comment: @Finies отправка письма работает. только именно значения $name, email, etc не передаются

Comment: Попробуйте всё же удалить строки 2-4 и 9-11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, в вашем массиве $_POST просто не должно быть ключа form1. То что вы дали название своей форме form1 никак не влияет на структуру массива отправляемых данных. Во вторых, вы полям формы назначили ID'ы, вместо имен. Имена становятся ключами массива POST, а не ID'ы. То есть атрибут name нужно было назначать в полях, а не в форме. Как-то вот так

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
```

Если вы хотите чтобы в вашем массиве $_POST был еще один массив form1 а в нем были элементы (например email, name и так далее), и чтобы вы могли обращаться к ним как-то так

```
$_POST['form1']['name']
```

то вам нужно называть свои поля как-то вот так

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="form1[name]" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
```

Если же вам это не нужно, а нужно просто передать какую-то метку формы отдельным значением, то можно использовать скрытое поле

```
<input type="hidden" name="form1" value="1" />
```

Comment: все сработало. спасибо. также помог комментарий @Finies чуть выше